# python threading for raspberry pi camera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a question on threading in python.

I have 3 applications for which I want to access the same resource (a camera).  I would like to start the camera up streaming frames and then each of these processes take frames as needed and at different resolutions (or I can scale the images later if that is not efficient).  I can get each of these three applications to run independently but have not found a way to thread them successfully.  All three have been learned from others and I am grateful for them sharing.  Credits below.

Application 1 streams the video feed to a web server.

```
with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=16) as camera:    
    output = StreamingOutput()
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

Application 2 grabs small frames to memory often for detecting motion and then if certain conditions are met an image is saved to disk.  In this case I want to grab low resolution frames for speeding up the analysis and also keeping them in memory only.  For the part of saving I am interested in grabbing a higher resolution file for disk

```
def captureTestImage(settings, width, height):
    command = "raspistill %s -w %s -h %s -t 200 -e bmp -n -o -" % (settings, width, height)
    imageData = io.BytesIO()
    imageData.write(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
    imageData.seek(0)
    im = Image.open(imageData)
    buffer = im.load()
    imageData.close()
    return im, buffer
while True:
    motionState = P3picam.motion()
    if motionState:
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
            camera.resolution = (1920,1080)  
            camera.capture(picPath + picName)
```

Application 3 grabs frames from a video stream and then uses openCV on them.

```
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Application 1 credits:  http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming
Application 2 credits:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yH7JHz9w
Application 3 credits: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/25/raspberry-pi-face-recognition/

Comment: What was the question please?

Comment: Are you asking about how to use multithreading?